# optimization - fit a curve with fixed degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, optimization, numerical-methods

Is there a handly solution to the optimization problem
$$
\min_{a\in \mathbb{R}^6} \int_X \mid a_1 + a_2x_1+a_3x_2+a_4x_1^2+a_5x_1x_2+a_6x_2^2 - \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} \mid \,dx_1dx_2 
$$
where $X$ is the unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^2$
?

Numerically, using standard routine on matlab I found a solution $a^\star=(0.317,0,0,0.7321,0,0.7321)$ ?

Is there any numerical scheme adapted for this kind of problem? I read about MPT (Multi-parametric programming solver) that I am trying to implement with a linear or quadratic formulation but I don't have good results for now....